# How to change plotly bar size

Tags: python, django, plotly

I am trying to plot a bar chart using python and plotly, but the size of the bar is high. I want to reduce the size of the bar.
Can anyone help me?
[image: image of baar plot]and I am sharing my code.

```
data_plots = go.Bar(x=df1['MeterReading_DateTime'], y= df1['ACT_IMP_TOT'],marker = {'color' : '#060805'},width = 1)
layout = {'title': '','xaxis': {'title': 'Date and time'},'yaxis': {'title': 'Total Import(KWH)'},'plot_bgcolor':'#8099b3' }
fig = {'data': data_plots, 'layout': layout}
plot_div = offline.plot(fig, output_type='div')
return plot_div
```

Comment: The size of the bar depends on your input data. What does it meant "is high"? Is it different from what you expect given the data? Please include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and include the dataframe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Comment: They give recommendations to change the height using styles or the layout property of the figure. https://community.plotly.com/t/cant-seem-to-change-default-height-on-graph/6742#:~:text=Nov%20%2717-,That%20height,-is%20set%20automatically

Comment: The maximum width specified for a bar graph is 1. I believe it is automatically calculated by the number of elements on the x-axis for the default graph size. So you can adjust the width to be narrower than 0.5 or 1 or less.